# sending a plotly graph by email with sendgrid, in a lambda script

Tags: python, amazon-s3, graph, plotly, sendgrid

our platform sends a weekly email to our users with data using sendgrid, and a lambda function.
i'm trying to add a graph to this email.

i use plotly to create this graph.

i tried converting the graph to html but that didnt work because the html uses a script to create the graph and sendgrid delete scripts from emails to protect the recievers.

so, i tried to get the graph as image in bytes and add it to img src like this -

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, [my byte array]"/>
```

but this also, didnt work.

so now, im trying to save the file directly to an s3 bucket and from there get the link and add it as src in the img element..

my problem is i cant manage to this with only bytes..
i looked for ways to save it directly from lambda to s3 but i didnt find anything...

any help will be appreciated!
thank you.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/v3/email-reports/

i used this solution..
with package chart_studio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.